# Return complex type from java ws

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, netbeans, apache-axis

I read a lot of articles about jax-ws and complex type, but I am confused. I don't know how to annotated my classes (or write Adapter or whatever) to return a complex type. I am using NetBeans 8 + axis2 + tomcat. And now I have this classes

This class is like Axis Web Services

```
public class GenerateResp {

Term t;

public Term getRes(Class1 p, Class2 r, float d) throws BusinessException{
    t = new Term();
    t.setText("text");
    return t;   
}
```

}

and second class

```
public class Term implements Serializable {

private String text;

public String getText(){
    return text;
}

public void setText(String s){
    text= s;
}
```

}

What should I do to get response with element like:

```
<term>text</term>
```

now all my responses looks like:

```
<ns:return/>
```

EDIT: Now it looks I have to `OMElement` as return parameter. So I will build XML tree manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Term implements Serializable {

private String text;
@XmlElement
public String getText(){
    return text;
}

public void setText(String s){
    text= s;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately responsse is still  `<ns:getRes xmlns:ns="http://test/com/xsd">
         <ns:return/>
      </ns:getRes>`